# boost::any library doesn't compile: "Array used as initializer" error

Tags: c++, boost, c++14

I'm using `boost::any` (among other Boost functionalities) in a C++ project.

The following compiles just fine on my Mac (MacBook Pro Retina running the latest version of Mavericks) with g++:

```
#include <boost/any.hpp>
```

but when I use Ubuntu Linux with g++ using the same compilation settings / flags, I get the following error:

```
In file included from /home/alexandergunnarson/Documents/Source Code/byu/library/collections.cpp:11:0,
                 from /home/alexandergunnarson/Documents/Source Code/byu/library/collections.h:4,
                 from /home/alexandergunnarson/Documents/Source Code/byu/library/main.cpp:16:
/usr/include/boost/any.hpp: In instantiation of ‘boost::any::holder<ValueType>::holder(const ValueType&) [with ValueType = char [5]]’:
/usr/include/boost/any.hpp:52:49:   required from ‘boost::any::any(const ValueType&) [with ValueType = char [5]]’
/home/alexandergunnarson/Documents/Source Code/byu/library/main.cpp:149:22:   required from here
/usr/include/boost/any.hpp:169:27: error: array used as initializer
               : held(value)
                       ^
```

`collections.cpp:11:0` is referring to is the `#include <boost/any.hpp>` statement.

I'm using g++ 4.9 from Sublime Text 3 with Ubuntu 14.04.

Is this a Boost problem or what?

Thanks for your help!

## Updated:

As T.C. used his "psychic powers" to predict, I was trying to cast string literals to `boost::any`. Now the code works after having gone through and put some string literals in a `string` constructor and edited some relevant functions.

Comment: `/home/alexandergunnarson/Documents/Source Code/byu/library/main.cpp:149:22:   required from here` post the code around that location.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My psychic powers say that you are trying to put a string literal inside a `boost::any`. This isn't allowed; string literals are arrays of `const char`s and arrays are not `CopyConstructible`, which `boost::any` requires.

Instead of

```
boost::any t("foo");
```

use

```
boost::any t(+"foo");
```

to force the array to decay to a pointer, or

```
boost::any t(std::string("foo")); // or "foo"s in C++14
```

to make it store a `std::string` instead.

Comment: `+"foo"` I have never seen this; What does it mean?

Comment: @ikh Applied to an array, unary `+` forces the array-to-pointer conversion and returns the resulting pointer.

Comment: Wow, I've never heard about that; Has it existed since a long ago, or added in a recent standard?

Comment: @ikh I'm fairly sure it's around since C++98.

Comment: This seems like a really obscure error. I'm impressed you answered it so quickly! Thanks! (It works now that I used ```string("my string literal")```)