# Boost::any assign string value

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, boost-any

> IDE - Clion, C++11,
>   Boost Version 1.57.0

Why doesn't work this code?

```
#include "boost/any.hpp"
...
boost::any var = 1550;   // Works
var = "String";  // Error
```

But works fine this one:

```
#include "boost/any.hpp"
...
boost::any var = 1550;   // Works
var = string("String");  // Works
```

Can you explain me reason of this error?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25943650/boostany-library-doesnt-compile-array-used-as-initializer-error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

boost::any — A class whose instances can hold instances of any type that satisfies ValueType requirements.
see this: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost/any.html

Comment: There is no relevant information in this answer. There is a link, but it's not even at all clear what part of the linked page you're thinking about.